# How to scroll to the bottom sheet in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using this code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      bottomSheet: ListTile(
        title: _messageField(context),
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: StreamBuilder(
                  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('videos')
                      .doc(widget.id)
                      .collection('comments')
                      .orderBy('time', descending: true)
                      .snapshots(),
                  builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return Scrollbar(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          controller: _controller,
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
```

So, the problem that I have is that the last item is covered with the `bottomsheet` this is how it looks:

[image: example]

What I want is that the last item is visible. Hope anyone can help.

This is the `messageField` if needed:

```
 Widget _messageField(BuildContext _context) {
    return Container(
      height: 57,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 2)),
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 30),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          _messageTextField(),
          _sendMessageButton(_context),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _messageTextField() {
    return SizedBox(
        width: 230,
        child: TextFormField(
            controller: commentcroller,
            cursorColor: Colors.black,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              hintText: "Enter a message",
            )));
  }

  Widget _sendMessageButton(BuildContext _context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
      child: Container(
        height: 40,
        child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.send,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              if (commentcroller.text.isEmpty) {
                return "Please enter a Message";
              } else {
                publishcomment();
              }
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

If you don't need it, tell me then I will remove it. If you need any other code please leave a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to handle this, one is to use `persistentBottomSheetController` to hide the bottom sheet when you are scrolling.

```dart
final _bottomSheetController = Scaffold.of(context).showBottomSheet((context) => null);
_bottomSheetController.close();
```

another one is to put your input as `bottomNavigation` which accept any widget as its child despite its name. This allow you to have the persistent input without the need to close or show it using any controller and it won't disturb your scaffold body.

```dart
Scaffold(
   bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
     elevation: 0, // hide the shadow
     child: ListTile(
        title: _messageField(context),
     ),
   )
)
```

Comment: im sorry but which input ?

Comment: ok sorry got it the second probably solution is good but actually why my widget scrolls a bit up when im scrolling down to the buttom . Like it scrolls automticly a bit back

Comment: have you try using different scrollPhysics because physics ? If your original question answered do mark the answer, and start a new question if you still have problem with the scroll

Answer (score 0):

You can change

> height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height ( Full screen height )

to

> MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * value, ( value = 0.5, 0.7 ...)